# How to query "Related List" header from Opportunity page via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, opportunity, related-list

I'm trying to query "Related List" header from Opportunity page via Javascript,

```
<h3 id="006g0000005dVS5_00Ng0000000p6b6_title">Phoenix Quotes</h3>
```

I know that "006g0000005dVS5" is Opportunity Id

I need to figure out what is this "00Ng0000000p6b6" ??
Any ideas?
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that IDs starting with "00N" are custom fields - or, in this case, custom related lists.

If you look at standard related lists, you'll see more readable identifiers like "RelatedActivityList" rather than an 18-digit ID.

Answer (score 0):

That Id is for an object called `CustomFieldDefinition`.

Here's how you can find that out for yourself in the future (if you're open to Execute Anonymous).

```
Id someId = Id.valueOf('00Ng0000000p6b6');
system.debug(someId.getSObjectType());
```

I do not see this `sObjectType` in my Salesforce Schema (Eclipse), but I haven't looked through a WSDL for it. If you need to programmatically reference it for your selectors, it may make sense to manually find the Ids and store the values in a custom setting. I think if you use a hierarchy custom setting it will be easier to reference on the page. Just add a field for each related list you want to search, and store the Id in it under the org default.